# Add a class name to certain rows of an admin-generated module

Tags: symfony1

I have a symfony project where I have a module called ImportBundle. For rows where `$import_bundle->getIsForTesting()`, I want the row to show up red. If I remember correctly, there's an easy way to add a class name to each row that meets a certain criteria, but I can't remember how its done. Can anyone help me remember what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supose you are using a tabular layout for your index so the simplest way to do this is to modify the _list_td_tabular.php partial in your module template folder. This partial takes care of a row representation so you could add a class if a condition is reached.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah yes, I vaguely remember reading about this somewhere. The solution I was trying to think of was actually something different but this is just as good. Thanks.